# IntelliJ Rider always has two of the same target when I Go To Declaration/Implementation

Tags: intellij-idea, rider

When I Ctrl+Click a method or class in IntelliJ Rider, I'd expect it to go that class/method. However, instead it brings up a "Select Target" dialog which always has two copies of the same class in it. Choosing between two of the same class is a pretty dumb step - does anyone know how to get rid of the second copy of the class so I can just go straight to the class without having to choose?

Screenshot of the behavior below:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File` -> `Invalidate Caches...` -> `Uncheck optional checkboxes` -> `Invalidate and Restart`

Invalidating **only** ReSharper caches and restarting helped me for `Rider 2021.3.3`.

[image]

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue this time around!

Comment: it comes back after restart, usually happens after debugging,

Comment: Yeah, it keeps coming back. I've seen up to 3 instances of the same item in the Select Target box. It's really annoying having to click several times for something as basic as going to a function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Rider just released an update today that fixed this. Huzzah!

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now, any idea what changed ?

Comment: @Shraneid Sadly Rider has degraded back to this for me as well after a recent update.

Comment: I think it's not the update that is fixed the problem but rather a cache invalidation that should occur when the update is installed. I tried to invalidate caches manually and it helped, like @Rub suggested in his answer.

Answer (score -2):

I resolved it by uninstalling Resharper.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Don't think this is a valid solution. I'd like to continue using Rider/ReSharper, not getting rid of it completely because of some inconvenience.